# Как сделать более профессионально?

Tags: javascript

Чем цикл неправилен?

```
function validate() {
    var name_teacher = document.forms["form_teacher"]["name_teacher"].value;
    var surname_teacher = document.forms["form_teacher"]["surname_teacher"].value;
    var vse = new Array(name_teacher, surname_teacher, )

    for (i = vse; i; i++) {
        if (i != null && i != "") {
            if (/[^a-z][а-я]/.test(i)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                alert(i);
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: всё налицо у Вас:   
Вы сделали переменную vse массивом, далее итератору I  Вы даете значение vse [1-ая ошибка],   
условие выхода из цикла- существование I, но при этом внутри цикла нет уничтожения I [2-ая ошибка]  
далее попытка инкрементировать (увеличить на единицу) массив- но это следствие 1-ой ошибки.   
итого 2.5 ошибки. как исправить чуть ниже в ответах.

Answer (score 2):

Я-бы сделал так:

```
function validate (f) {
    var rc = true,
            is_valid = function (v) {
                return (v != null && v.length && /[^a-z][а-я]/.test(v)); 
            };

    if (!is_valid(f.elements["name_teacher"].value)) {
        alert(f.elements["name_teacher"].value);
        rc = false;
    }
    else if (!is_valid(f.elements["surname_teacher"].value)) {
        alert(f.elements["surname_teacher"].value);
        rc = false;
    }
    return rc;
}

<form onsubmit="return(validate(this))" ...>
...
</form>
```

Просто тут цикл из двух элементов смысла нету. Если вы, таки, настаиваете на цикле, то вот:

```
function validate (f) {
    var rc = true,
        fields = ["name_teacher", "surname_teacher"],
                is_valid = function (v) {
                    return (v != null && v.length && /[^a-z][а-я]/.test(v)); 
                };

    for( var i = 0, max_i = fields.length; i < max_i && rc; i++ ) {
        var field_value = f.elements[fields[i]];

        if (!is_valid(field_value)) {
            alert( fields[i] + ": '" + field_value + "'" );
            rc = false; 
        } 
    }
    return rc;
}
```

Но наверно удобнее было-бы все это свернуть примерно таким образом:

```
var validate = {
    is_valid: function (v) {
        return (v != null && v.length && /[^a-z][а-я]/.test(v)); 
    },
    form: function (f) {
        var rc = true;

        for (var i = 0, max_i = f.elements.length; i < max_i && rc; i++) {
            var e = f.elements[i];

            switch (e.name) {
                case "name_teacher":
                case "surname_teacher":
                    if (!this.is_valid(e.value)) {
                        alert(e.name + ": '" + e.value + "'");
                        rc = false;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return rc;
    }
};

<form onsubmit="return(validate.form(this))" ...>
...
</form>
```

Comment: this.form ?? ну ну :)

Comment: Да, действительно просто this, просто по привычке как к input-ам прописал

Answer (score 1):

```
for( var i=0; i<vse.length; i++ ) {
    if(vse[i] != null && i != "") {
    //хотя зачем тут на null проверка?..
    //ну да не суть...
        if(/[а-яА-Я]/.test(vse[i])) { //регулярка явно странная у Вас была :)
            //ну а тут return делать странное действие...
            //тут как я понял идею вообще ничего ненадо делать
            //вообщем все ок идем по массиву дальше...
        }
        else {
            //ну а уже тут можно и return сделать...
            //т.е. если где-то чтото не так возвращаем false
            alert(i);
            return false;
        }
    }

    //ну и если мы так ниразу и не вернули false - смело возвращаем true
    return true;
}
```

Опять таки это все из разряда попытки проявления екстрасенсорных способностей т.к. предугадать чего вы хотите от этого кода, как вы понимаете я не могу ( увы не екстрасенс :( )

Comment: Зачем else, если можно сразу указать отрицание в условие?

Comment: Потому что так я лучше указываю на ошибки автора и меньше изменяю код, что для его уровня, по-моему, жизненно необходимо, естественно я бы else не писал в реальном коде

Answer (score 1):

1) Ваш код не рабочий,  т.к. он ошибочен синтаксически
Исправил, оптимизировал:

```
function validate() {
  var teacher = document.forms["form_teacher"],
      val = [],
      re = /[^a-z][а-я]/,
      c_val, i, ei;

  val.push( teacher["name_teacher"].value );
  val.push( teacher["surname_teacher"].value );

  for ( i = 0, ei = val.length; i < ei; i++ ){
    c_val = val[i];
    if ( ( c_val != null ) && ( c_val != '' ) ){
      if ( re.test( c_val ) return true;
      else alert( c_val );
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

2) Ваш код логически не работоспособен! Тут уже не исправить....
посмотрите: 
сомнительный вид конструкции document.forms["form _teacher"]["name _teacher"]
врятле ваше re обозначает то что вы хотите действительно; 
очень странный выход из цикла

Comment: С странным выходом из цикла согласен на все 100

Answer (score 0):

мой вариант:

```
MyValidator = function() {}
MyValidator.prototype.onlySymbols = function (text)
{
    return (text != null && text.length && /[a-z0-9]/i.test(text));
}

function validate(form) {
    var mv = new MyValidator();
    for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
        var el = form.elements[i];
        var v = el.getAttribute('validator');
        if (typeof(v) == 'string') {
            if (typeof(mv[v]) != 'function') {
                // тут мы можем применить какой то стиль. например красный бордер
                return false;
            }
            var isValid = mv[v](el.value);
            if (!isValid) {
                // тут мы можем применить какой то стиль. например красный бордер
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

как это применять:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate(this)">
...
   <input type="text" name="..." validator="onlySymbols"/>
...
</form>
```

Если нужно сделать другой фильтр, например только цифры:

добавляем соответсвующий валидатор:

```
MyValidator.prototype.onlyNumbers = function (text) {
   // и тут пишем соответсвующую валидацию
}
```

ну и в форме

```
<form onsubmit="return validate(this)">
...
    <input type="text" name="..." validator="onlyNumbers"/>
...
</form>
```

Comment: Это все очень круто но явно код не уровня ТСа :)<br>
Человек не мог нормально просто for и логику уровня if else написать, не думаю что он поймет все это, особенно протитип - это вы очень сильно загнули...<br>
Не все javascript программисты толком понимают что это...

Comment: Зачем каждый раз при проверке делать **var mv = new MyValidator();** ?) Если уж делаете универсально, то делайте до конца!

Comment: Ваш вариант ? Создать глобал и проверять или он существует ?

Comment: У вас и так есть глобал! Притом не переменная, а свойство, и имя ему **MyValidator**, и его с таким-же успехом можно удалить...